# Text Analysis Services/Libraries

Tags: text-mining, text-analysis

Right now I'm getting tweets from Twitter Streaming API and doing some semantic analysis. Basically I want to extract tweets about people leaving home and going somewhere (a place) for a vacation or business trip or some related matters, so I can recommend them a weather app that can show the real-time weather of the place they're going to.

Now I'm using key words like: `going to, heading for, leaving for, trip` and `travel` for the streaming API and then I feed the filtered tweets to `AYLIEN` to do `semantic labeling`. I'm currently using labels: `trip, travel, vacation` and `holiday`. As long as any of those labels has a score higher than 0.01, I consider the corresponding tweet as the one I want.

But I found AYLIEN is not very satisfying for my task, I still get a lot of tweets such as *`I am leaving for a while`*, *`Babe is leaving for 2 weeks`* and *`I'm leaving for work`*, which are not what I want.

So I want to know if anybody know some descent text analysis services or libraries that can help me to achieve my goal. Thanks.

Comment: Your question is much too broad and vague for us to hope to answer.  But there are a number of content analysis services out there, e.g. https://cloud.google.com/prediction/.

Comment: @dimo414 Thanks for the info. It seems helpful to me.